# Heroku: Wrong number of arguments for rake precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

Background: I am attempting to update a Heroku app from 14 to 20. I believe I have all the gems bundled properly and am now hoping to push the app.

Given similar cases I have come across online, my guess is that I must update some gem. However, when I run update, it appears that all gems are fully up-to-date.

```
~/Doc/gentle-island-2510 | master >8  git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 41, done.
Counting objects: 100% (41/41), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 4.45 KiB | 2.23 MiB/s, done.
Total 33 (delta 21), reused 6 (delta 2)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 1.17.3
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.0.0
remote:        Purging Cache. Changing stack from cedar-14 to heroku-20
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.17.3
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 BUNDLE_GLOBAL_PATH_APPENDS_RUBY_SCOPE=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
...
remote:        Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 59 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Removing bundler (1.17.3)
remote:        Bundle completed (134.54s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:111:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37:in `build'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `block in build'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `inject'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `build'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `block in app'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `app'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_f44696fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to gentle-island-2510.
remote:
```

Comment: Same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing `Gemfile.lock` then running `bundle install` and pushing a new commit to Heroku.

I also added an environment variable `RAILS_ENV=production` to the app in Heroku (Settings > Config Vars). Once I added this I was able to push the application successfully.